# How to check if a string contains a word at a case statement - SQLite

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, substring, case

This is my code:

```sql
SELECT 
CASE your_text
  WHEN contains('hate') THEN 'hater'
  WHEN contains('love') THEN 'lover'
  ELSE 'other'
END haterOrLover,
count(*) AS total_count
FROM a_table
GROUP BY haterOrLover
```

If only contains() existed!

I want to count how many haters, lovers there are and the result to be at this format:

```
+--------------+-------------+  
| haterOrLover | total_count |  
+--------------+-------------+  
| hater        | 1           |  
+--------------+-------------+  
| lover        | 2           |  
+--------------+-------------+  
| other        | 1           |  
+--------------+-------------+
```

Tried:

```sql
WHEN your_text like '%hate%' THEN 'hater'
```

```sql
WHEN '%hate%' THEN 'hater'
```

but didn't work.

How to check if a record contains a specific word at the 'your_text' column?

**Edit**
How to reproduce:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a_table
(
id         char(10)      PRIMARY KEY,
your_text  char(250)     NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO a_table
    (id, your_text)
VALUES
    (1, 'I love dogs'),
    (2, 'I hate cats'),
    (3, 'I like rabits'),
    (4, 'I love haskis');
```

Thank you

---

**Solution**:

```sql
SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN your_text like '%hate%' THEN 'hater'
  WHEN your_text like '%love%' THEN 'lover'
  ELSE 'other'
END haterOrLover,
count(*) AS total_count
FROM a_table
GROUP BY haterOrLover
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try it :

```
with cte as (
SELECT 
CASE when your_text like ('%hate%') THEN 'hater'
     when your_text like ('%love%') THEN 'lover'
     ELSE 'other'
     END haterOrLover FROM a_table )
select haterOrLover , count(*) as total_count from cte
group by (haterOrLover)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Actually, 'your_text' after CASE was wrong at the initial code.